# SELECT * and TOP() in MDX

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx, dmv

How can I preview my tables in the SASS database server using MDX. I want to explore the model that was build in the SASS server by a different team and I would like to do some data exploration. I am use to SQL and able to preview top 10-100 rows of the data set and am unable to figure out how to ask a simple

SELECT [TableName]

FROM [ModelName]

I want to preview all fields in the [TableName] in the [Model] to see what the data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

So you dont have a specific table where you can say Select * from Model. However you have DMV in SSAS that will let you explore what the objects. You can explore the Dmv details here 
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/use-dynamic-management-views-dmvs-to-monitor-analysis-services?view=sql-server-2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPEk4.jpg)

For example I want to see all the dimensions in my cube

```
select * from $System.MDSCHEMA_DIMENSIONS
```

Result 
[image]

Now I want to see all the members of geography

```
select * from $System.MDSCHEMA_MEMBERS  
where [CUBE_NAME]='$Geography' and [dimension_unique_name]='[Geography]'
```

Result [image]

Comment: Thank you this makes more sense. Is there a way to query the whole dimension_unique_name to get the table output is your results to see all the data in that table?

Comment: @KenanTufekci of this helps may I suggest that you mark it as answer or upvote it, based on how helpfully it was. As as far as the unique name goes, please post another question and I will be happy to help.